# Maximum and minimum function $f(x,y)=x$ on $\left\{ (x,y): x^4+y^4 = 4xy \right\} $

Tags: calculus, optimization

Determine minimum and maximum of function $f(x,y)=x$ on $\left\{ (x,y): x^4+y^4 = 4xy \right\} $.

I used Lagrange multiplier and received that

1. $f(3^{3/8},3^{1/8}) = 3^{3/8}$ is maximum
2. $f(-3^{3/8},-3^{1/8}) = -3^{3/8}$ is maximum

Could you tell me is it correct?

Comment: Mathematica agrees with you.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need a Mathematica code to do this kind of check in the future:

```
FindMinimum[{x,x^4+y^4==4x y},{x,0},{y,0}]
-3^{3/8}//N
FindMaximum[{x,x^4+y^4==4x y},{x,0},{y,0}]
3^{3/8}//N
```

Output:

```
{-1.5098,{x->-1.5098,y->-1.1472}}
{-1.5098}
{1.5098,{x->1.5098,y->1.1472}}
{1.5098}
```

You need [a bit different code](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%28x%29%20when%20x%5E4%2by%5E4==4x%20y,%20y%20is%20real) for Wolfram|Alpha:

```
min(x) when x^4+y^4==4x y, y is real
```